# driver oci requires PDO API version 20080721; this is PDO version 20150127 oci8

Tags: php, oracle, macos, laravel-5, oci8

I downloaded oci8 and pdo_oci.

When running the PHP artisan server I encountered the following problem:

```
error :  driver oci requires PDO API version 20080721; this is PDO version 20150127 oci8
```

How can I solve this error?
Thanks for your help!

Comment: I edited this question, khalil - please note how a question should be posted here and use it as a reference in the future.
Otherwise the harsh SO users will give you some trouble :/ ....

Comment: Please give the version of PHP you installed.